# Can anybody explain how its printing output as "ink"

Tags: c, pointers, obfuscation

I am new to pointers in C.  I know the basic concepts.  In the below code, why is it printing the "ink" as its output?

```
#include<stdio.h>


main()
{
    static char *s[]={"black","white","pink","violet"};

    char **ptr[]={s+3,s+2,s+1,s},***p;

    p=ptr;

    ++p;

    printf("%s",**p+1);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Step through it with a debugger and watch what happens to the variables.

Comment: @Paul, I'm guessing based on giri's profile that no.  @Dave, my feeling is that this is a paper-and-pencil question.

Answer (score 15):

Let's trace it:

```
ptr = {pointer to "violet", pointer to "pink", pointer to "white", pointer to "black"}

p = ptr --> *p = pointer to "violet"

++p -->     *p = pointer to "pink"
```

This implies that:

```
*p = {'p','i','n','k','\0'}
```

Which means:

```
**p = 'p'
**p + 1 = 'i'
```

so `**p + 1` is a pointer to this string: `{'i', 'n', 'k', '\0'}`, which is simply `"ink"`.

Answer (score 4):

`s` is an array of `char *` (which represent strings).

`ptr` is an array of pointers to pointers (pointing to the values of `s`, which are pointers to strings)

`p` is set to point to `ptr[0]` (which is a pointer to `s[3]` or "violet")

`p` is incremented to point to `ptr[1]`, which points to `s[2]` or "pink"

In the printf statement `p` is dereferenced twice. The first deref is a pointer to `s[2]`, the second deref gets you the value of `s[2]` - "pink". The +1 shifts the pointer to the start of "pink" on by one char, so printing from here to the end of the string will give you "ink".

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise that you work backwards from what you know was printed (the 'ink' in 'pink') and see where the different variables must be pointing for that to happen.

Remember that an array can be viewed as a pointer to its first element and that a string can similarly be viewed as a pointer to its first character.

Answer (score 0):

> static char
>   *s[]={"black","white","pink","violet"};
>
> ```
>      In the above statement you are initialize. 
>
>      char **ptr[]={s+3,s+2,s+1,s}
>
>        In the above statement you are assign pointer s value to ptr
> ```
>
> value. And declare a triple pointer.
>
> ```
>     p=ptr; 
>     In the above statement you assign the double pointer address to
> ```
>
> triple pointer.
>
> ```
>    ++p; 
>
>    In the above statement you increment the triple pointer value. So
> ```
>
> that time it point to "pink".
>
> ```
>    But you are print the **p+1. That time it will print only "ink".
> ```
>
> If you print **(p+1), that time it
>   will print "white". Because  in the
>   initialization of double pointer you
>   initialize the "s+2". So that time it
>   will points to the "white".

Comment: Note that `p` is an array of double pointers. In C an array is equivalent to a pointer, so `p` is actually a triple pointer as well.